# Addition of two matrices in SWI prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog

I need to get addition of two matrices and this the SWI prolog code of it that I tried. But
the answer is wrong here. I want to be corrected it.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

m_add(M1, M2, M3) :- maplist(mm_helper(M2), M1, M3).

mm_helper(M2, I1, M3) :- maplist(dot(I1), M2, M3).

dot(V1, V2, P) :- maplist(sum,V1,V2,P).

sum(N1,N2,N3) :- N3 is N1+N2.
```

when give the question as follows,

```
?- m_add([[2,1,3],[4,2,5]],[[4,0,1],[1,7,1]],R).
```

the answer appears like this.

```
R = [[[6, 1, 4], [3, 8, 4]], [[8, 2, 6], [5, 9, 6]]].
```

But the answer should be,

```
R = [[6, 1, 4],[5, 9, 6]].
```

Answer (score 2):

actually, it's simpler than you think:

```
m_add(M1, M2, M3) :- maplist(maplist(sum), M1, M2, M3).
sum(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X+Y.
```

test:

```
?- m_add([[2,1,3],[4,2,5]],[[4,0,1],[1,7,1]],R).
R = [[6, 1, 4], [5, 9, 6]].
```

if you are dealing with integers, [plus/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=plus/3) can be handy, as it can compute 'backward':

```
m_plus(M1, M2, M3) :- maplist(maplist(plus), M1, M2, M3).

?- m_plus([[2,1,3],[4,2,5]],[[4,0,1],[1,7,1]],R).
R = [[6, 1, 4], [5, 9, 6]].

?- m_plus([[2,1,3],[4,2,5]],B,$R).
B = [[4, 0, 1], [1, 7, 1]].
```

`$R` it's a SWI-Prolog 'trick' to get remembered top level variables...

A final note: CLP(FD) it's a powerful library, but if don't need its actual capabilities, best to stick with native arithmetic...

Comment: I tried this and it is working properly. thanks a lot. I am studying prolog now and can you please give me some references me to study simply. specially the matrix in prolog. thank you.

Comment: Prolog isn't meant for matrix algebra. There is nothing I know, apart some code I wrote. A good exercise: try to write the matrix addition without maplist. you will need 2 predicates for looping rows/columns...

Comment: Ok I will try to do it. But I have another problem. If I want to add two matrices with characters what should I do?

Comment: dunno, what it means ? do you have character codes ?

Comment: ex: m_add([[x],[y]],[[x],[y]],R).                                            R=[[2x],[2y]]

Comment: You means algebra symbols. You must define your rule, then just replace `plus` with your rule.